# How can I safely override the django.contrib.admin.utils quote() method?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

It appears that the `quote()` and `unquote()` methods inside `django.contrib.admin.utils` do not effectively handle underscores in primary keys. Specifically, I have some string-type primary keys that look like `cus_C2xVQnht` and when I use the django admin interface to edit them via the small pencil icon, the popup window will display an error like `Customer with ID "cusÂxVQnht" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?` (it is converting the **C2** to the codepoint **00C2**, aka **Â**. This is true for other valid codepoints as well (00C7, 00C6, 001B, etc)

If I manually go to the customers model and find the ID, I can pull it up and edit it just fine, but it seems the URL encoding doesn't work right when the primary key has an underscore in it.

After quite a lot of digging I managed to find these two functions buried deep inside `django.contrib.admin.utils`:

```
def quote(s):
    """
    Ensure that primary key values do not confuse the admin URLs by escaping
    any '/', '_' and ':' and similarly problematic characters.
    Similar to urllib.parse.quote(), except that the quoting is slightly
    different so that it doesn't get automatically unquoted by the Web browser.
    """
    if not isinstance(s, str):
        return s
    res = list(s)
    for i in range(len(res)):
        c = res[i]
        if c in """:/_#?;@&=+$,"[]<>%\n\\""":
            res[i] = '_%02X' % ord(c)
    return ''.join(res)


def unquote(s):
    """Undo the effects of quote(). Based heavily on urllib.parse.unquote()."""
    mychr = chr
    myatoi = int
    list = s.split('_')
    res = [list[0]]
    myappend = res.append
    del list[0]
    for item in list:
        if item[1:2]:
            try:
                myappend(mychr(myatoi(item[:2], 16)) + item[2:])
            except ValueError:
                myappend('_' + item)
        else:
            myappend('_' + item)
    return "".join(res)
```

They appear to be called somewhere in the admin template rendering process, but I couldn't figure out where/how often/all the locations, so I decided to do a quick monkey patch to decide if it was worth pursuing as a solution: I changed all the underscores in `quote()` and `unquote()` except for the one in the list of problem characters in `quote` to dots...for example:

- `'_%02X'` in `quote()`becomes `'.%02X'`
- `split('_')` in `unquote()` becomes `split('.')`
- `myappend('_' + item)` in `unquote()` becomes `myappend('.' + item)`

Upon doing this, the admin works correctly and it appears that the links attached to the edit icons on related fields are to the correct model instances, so I can edit them by clicking the pencil icons and don't get the error message noted above.

**All that said, I can't seem to find a way to safely override these two methods. I really would rather not change the primary keys to eliminate the underscores** because there are a lot of linked models in my database and it just seems like it will become a huge pain. This fix seems much easier and more reliable, and given that it worked properly on previous versions of Django I don't see how it's a bad idea to implement.

**So, how can I override those methods?** Or, as a related question, is there something I can do in the `__str__` methods of my models to alleviate this problem? I'd do that much sooner than start writing custom classes that override Django admin internals. If there is no other solution, I would need some help in properly restructuring my database to adjust the primary keys, but I can say that these keys work perfectly on the "old" site I'm working on, which runs Django 1.11.6 and Python 2.7.9 (vs the current Django 2.1.1 and Python 3.6.5)

Please let me know if I can provide any more info. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in django 2.2. See https://github.com/django/django/commit/e4df8e6dc021fa472fa77f9b835db74810184748

Comment: Thank you! I've actually been using that specific commit in my requirements.txt for quite some time in order to work around this problem. Cheers :)